# How to get Consumers Current and Messages Total queue parameters by uploading JSP (with java code in it) at WEBLOGIC server?

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic

I need to get parameters like Consumers Current and Messages Total from queues table. I need to create a jsp with such functionality, upload it on server and run it on server. As far as I got it it would be pure java code inside of jsp file.

And here is the question: what code to put inside of it to get needed parameters? How to get this queue parameters using java and print them on the server? Could anyone please help me?

Update: I found this code. But I don't know what to insert there instead of "123" and do I need all this properties for connection if I put jsp on server?

```
 public void countMessages() throws NamingException, JMSException {
       Properties env = new Properties();
       env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://123");
       env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "123");
       env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "123");
       env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "123");
       InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
       Destination queue = (Destination) ctx.lookup("123");
       JMSDestinationRuntimeMBean destMBean = JMSRuntimeHelper.getJMSDestinationRuntimeMBean(ctx, queue);
       System.out.println("count: " + destMBean.getMessagesCurrentCount());
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 123, use your normal admin server logon information:

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://your_host:port");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
Destination queue = (Destination) ctx.lookup("jndi name of your queue");
```

That setup is how a *client* connects and finds out JMS information and should work just fine inside of a JSP page.

Comment: castling , thank you for your reply. My post did not fit in comment letter limit so I created a new question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030022/how-to-get-the-list-of-jms-queues-from-summary-of-resources-table-of-jms-module) Please check it out if you can.