# List all queue names for a JMSBroker via jndi

Tags: java, jms, jndi

I have created a Generic Java JMSBroker connector to monitor MQs and would like to add a method to be able to list all the available queues. I am using JNDI and javax.jms api.

Is there a generic way to do this for any provider?

I dont want provider specific api imports in my code.

Or this is not possible?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030022/how-to-get-the-list-of-jms-queues-from-summary-of-resources-table-of-jms-module

Comment: Hmm was hoping to not go down the jmx way

Comment: As far as I know there is no generic way to list the queues, though your JMS Provider implementation might provide a way....

Comment: @user2642282 I know amq provides a way `getDestinations()` i think. Was hoping for a generic way otherwise I would have to cater for all different implementations

Comment: @user2642282 also with jmx (the link you pointed me to) you need to specify package name for jms provider `weblogic.management.remote` . This is not generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in the JMS API to cope with this. Many implementations has their ways to allow such things though. So you need to make custom logic for each JMS implementation that allows queue listing.

Although no requirement for JMS, many JMS solutions define all (or at least some) queues and topics in a JNDI directory. If you know this is the case - you may ask that directory for all entries and look for queues.